# Unable to create or edit avd in eclipse after updating to 22.6

Tags: android

Please help me out with this.After updating to 22.6 i am unable to create a new avd or edit the existing one,Everything is working good but my OK button doesn't go grey.
I have all the system images installed like ARM EABI v7a,Intel x86 Atom as well as MIPS for the desired api level,but still its not working and also not showing any error.

Comment: Finally the problem is solved in SDK 22.6.2,Now we can create AVD directly from AVD Manager.Thanks to Google.

Comment: Good to hear that, Thank you.

Comment: @user2384410 I just installed SDK tools version 22.6.2 and Android API 4.4.2 on Mac OSx and the issue still persists. I am using JDK 8. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug from Google side, this problem found after "ADT 22.6" update.

I was successful to create an AVD by opening "**AVD manager.exe**" from "**Android SDK**" for creating new AVD try to open directly AVD Manager.exe in SDK folder.

You can check for this bug here.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

It is clearly stated in subject it self `SDK 22.6 can't create avd`

Comment: Hey man i don't have AVDManager.exe in my sdk folder,I searched it in sdk\tools\lib, it's also not there.Where can i find this.